# How to determine how unique a word is?

Tags: c#

I have a text file with around 300,000 words. Each word is 5 letters.

I'd like to be able to determine how unique each word is on the internet.

An idea I had was to Google the word and see how many results it yielded. Unfortunately, this is against their TOS.

I was trying to think of any other way but it would have to involve querying some website a lot and I doubt they would appreciate that much.

Anyone have any other ideas? Programming language doesn't matter that much but I would prefer C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look up the frequency 'in books' you could use the [Google Ngram dataset](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html), but that's not 'for the internet'.  If this is for academic purposes the [Bing alternative](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/collaboration/focus/cs/web-ngram.aspx) might work also and it is based on internet-frequencies.

Comment: Well, the thing is that they're not real words. Just pronounceable strings of characters. They could be user names, domain names, etc. So I'm not sure if checking books would be ideal. It'd be a good starting point though.

Answer (score 2):

If your words do not contain slang, I would recommend looking at [public domain books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPublic_domain_books).  The issue here is that most of these books will be older, so you really will be getting a *snapshot in time of how popular a word is* (or I guess was).  The plus side is that these books are freely available in text file format allowing you to easily mine them for data.

One thing to note, if you're in the US and plan on using [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org) to get the books, they have a rule that the website is intended only for human users.  There is a [page that tells you how to get the same data via mirror](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aInformation_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages).